# Buttons are not appearing

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

**Note: I am new to React Native.** The code below is supposed to be a calculator run using React Native. I am having trouble with the buttons of this calculator code appearing. There is no error when the code runs, so I don't understand why the buttons do not appear.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

const inputButtons = [
    [1, 2, 3, '/'],
    [4, 5, 6, '*'],
    [7, 8, 9, '-'],
    [0, '.', '=', '+']
];


const Style = StyleSheet.create({
    rootContainer: {
        flex: 1
    },

    displayContainer: {
        flex: 2,
        backgroundColor: '#193441'
    },

    inputContainer: {
        flex: 8,
        backgroundColor: '#3E606F'
    },

    inputButton: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: '#91AA9D'
    },

    inputButtonText: {
        fontSize: 22,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white'
    },
    inputRow: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row'
    }
});
<View style={Style.rootContainer}>
    <View style={Style.displayContainer}></View>
    <View style={Style.inputContainer}></View>
</View>

export default class ReactCalculator extends Component {

     render() {
         return (
            <View style={Style.rootContainer}>
                <View style={Style.displayContainer}></View>
                <View style={Style.inputContainer}>
                    {this._renderInputButtons()}
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
    _renderInputButtons() {
        let views = [];

        for (var r = 0; r < inputButtons.length; r ++) {
            let row = inputButtons[r];

            let inputRow = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i ++) {
                let input = row[i];

                inputRow.push(
                    <InputButton value={input} key={r + "-" + i} />
                );
            }

            views.push(<View style={Style.inputRow} key={"row-" + r}>{inputRow}</View>)
        }

        return views;
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: '#193441'}}></View>
            <View style={{flex: 8, backgroundColor: '#3E606F'}}></View>
        </View>
    )

}


}
```

**Newest code:** - receiving errors when I am not receiving the errors, the buttons are appearing in the incorrect places.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Button,
    TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';

const inputButton = [
    [1, 2, 3, '/'],
    [4, 5, 6, '*'],
    [7, 8, 9, '-'],
    [0, '.', '=', '+']
];


const Style = StyleSheet.create({
    rootContainer: {
        flex: 1
    },

    displayContainer: {
        flex: 2,
        backgroundColor: '#193441'
    },

    inputContainer: {
        flex: 8,
        backgroundColor: '#3E606F'
    },

    inputButton: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: '#91AA9D'
    },

    inputButtonText: {
        fontSize: 22,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white'
    },
    inputRow: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row'
    }
});
<View style={Style.rootContainer}>
    <View style={Style.displayContainer}></View>
    <View style={Style.inputContainer}></View>
</View>

export default class ReactCalculator extends Component {

     render() {
         return (
            <TouchableHighlight style={Style.inputButton}
                                underlayColor="#193441"
                                onPress={this.props.onPress}>
                <Text style={Style.inputButtonText}>{this.props.value}</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }
    _renderInputButton() {
    let views = [];

    for (var r = 0; r < inputButton.length; r ++) {
        let row = inputButton[r];

        let inputRow = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i ++) {
            let input = row[i].toString();

            inputRow.push(
            <InputButton
                value={input}
                onPress={this._onInputButtonPressed.bind(this, input)}
                key={r + "-" + i}/>
        );
    }

    _onInputButtonPressed(input) {
        alert(input)
    }

        views.push(<View style={Style.inputRow} key={"row-" + r}>{inputRow}</View>)
    }

    return views;
}



}
```

Comment: Try removing the second render method in your component.

Comment: @user2313300 I removed the _renderInputButtons() and nothing happened.

Comment: No... you have two render() functions in your code. If the code in your app is the same that you posted, you have a second render function at the bottom of the component

Comment: @user2313300 I deleted the second render() function that you are referencing, but I am getting an error saying: "this._renderInputButton is not a function."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your code i found some problem:

**1.** method `this._renderInputButton()` undefined because when you declare the method you write `_renderinputButton()`. You must call the method with the same name. (React Native is case sensitive)

**2.** I not found component `InputButton` on your code. How you create the component?

I think the problem why your code not working like that. Maybe you can give me where you get the code.

*Edit*#1

You can create `InputButton` separate with file `index.js`. And then write in file `InputButton.js` :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

const Style = StyleSheet.create({
     inputButton: {
           flex: 1,
           alignItems: 'center',
           justifyContent: 'center',
           borderWidth: 0.5,
           borderColor: '#91AA9D',
     },
     inputButtonText: {
           fontSize: 22,
           fontWeight: 'bold',
           color: 'white',
     },
   });

  export default class InputButton extends Component {

  render() {
      return (
          <View style={Style.inputButton}>
            <Text style={Style.inputButtonText}>{this.props.value}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

}
```

And you can added `import InputButton from './InputButton'` in file index.js like :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, AppRegistry, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import InputButton from './InputButton';

const inputButton = [
  [1, 2, 3, '/'],
  [4, 5, 6, '*'],
  [7, 8, 9, '-'],
  [0, '.', '=', '+'],
];

const Style = StyleSheet.create({
  rootContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  displayContainer: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: '#193441',
  },

  inputContainer: {
    flex: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#3E606F',
  },

  inputButton: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#91AA9D',
  },

  inputButtonText: {
    fontSize: 22,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },
  inputRow: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});

export default class routerFlax extends Component {
  _renderInputButton() {
    let views = [];

    for (var r = 0; r < inputButton.length; r++) {
      let row = inputButton[r];

      let inputRow = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        let input = row[i];

        inputRow.push(<InputButton value={input} key={r + '-' + i} />);
      }

      views.push(
        <View style={Style.inputRow} key={'row-' + r}>{inputRow}</View>,
      );
    }

    return views;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={Style.rootContainer}>
        <View style={Style.displayContainer} />
        <View style={Style.inputContainer}>
          {this._renderInputButton()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

*Edi*#2

If you want to declare in one file, you can follow this code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, AppRegistry, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const inputButton = [
  [1, 2, 3, '/'],
  [4, 5, 6, '*'],
  [7, 8, 9, '-'],
  [0, '.', '=', '+'],
];

const Style = StyleSheet.create({
  rootContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  displayContainer: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: '#193441',
  },

  inputContainer: {
    flex: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#3E606F',
  },

  inputButton: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#91AA9D',
  },

  inputButtonText: {
    fontSize: 22,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },
  inputRow: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },

});

const InputButton = ({value}) => {
  return (
            <View style={Style.inputButton}>
                <Text style={Style.inputButtonText}>{value}</Text>
            </View>
        )
}

export default class routerFlax extends Component {
  _renderInputButton() {
    let views = [];

    for (var r = 0; r < inputButton.length; r++) {
      let row = inputButton[r];

      let inputRow = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        let input = row[i];

        inputRow.push(<InputButton value={input} key={r + '-' + i} />);
      }

      views.push(
        <View style={Style.inputRow} key={'row-' + r}>{inputRow}</View>
      );
    }

    return views;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={Style.rootContainer}>
        <View style={Style.displayContainer} />
        <View style={Style.inputContainer}>
          {this._renderInputButton()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

just added component `InputButton` like :

```
const InputButton = ({value}) => {
return (
        <View style={Style.inputButton}>
            <Text style={Style.inputButtonText}>{value}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

---

In my emulator this code working like :

[image: Image Calculator Apps]

I hope my answer give you ide and finish your problem. Happy Coding!

Comment: I was using a tutorial, but they were using multiple js documents and but I want to try to use only one document. Here is the link: https://kylewbanks.com/blog/react-native-tutorial-part-2-designing-a-calculator

Comment: I read tutorial, you missed one step. You can create InputButton.js for declare component ` <InputButton /> `. I edit my answer, you can follow that for your problem.. i hope my answer helping you.

Comment: You're welcome... i glad to help you. Can you give me upvoting for my answer. I am very grateful if you can give it.

Comment: Of course, and hopefully now you can upvote my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regular button for your _renderInputButton function

```
_renderInputButton() {
    let views = [];

    for (var r = 0; r < inputButton.length; r ++) {
        let row = inputButton[r];

        let inputRow = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i ++) {
            let input = row[i].toString();

            inputRow.push(
                <Button title={input}
                        key={r + "-" + i} />
            );
        }

        views.push(<View style={Style.inputRow} key={"row-" + r}>{inputRow}</View>)
    }

    return views;
}
```

and don't forget to import the button component

```
import {
View,
Text,
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Button,
} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Now the numbers of the buttons appear, but are not appearing in the correct places. I am receiving this warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onPress` is marked as required in `Button`, but its value is `undefined`.

Comment: you need to make a function to handle the button pressed. Because react recognize button used to be clickable, you can make an empty function if you still not able to figure out what to do with the button.

for buttons layout you can experiment with other layout component, such as flexbox or gridview, etc. So you can get the one which suitable with your needs

Comment: I tried using the `TouchableHighlight` instead of `View` and added more code, but I am still receiving errors. I put the new code in the question type.